# Cannot run OData Connected Service tool and compatiblity errors

Tags: sitecore-commerce, visual-studio

After upgrading to XC 9.3 I could not run the OData Connected Service tool. I fixed this by updating the Microsoft.OData.Client to version 7.6.3, but while regenerating the `ServiceProxy` for XC 9.3 I now get compatibility errors with the generated code.

NB. this is applicable to 9.3 and lower versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you are using a OData Connected Service version that is compatible with OData Client version 6.19.0.

The OData Connected Service tool is (automatically in VS) upgraded to v0.7.1 and this version no longer supports the correct OData Client version.
From v0.5 onwards it is only compatible with Microsoft.OData.Client to version 7.6.3.
See here for details: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=laylaliu.ODataConnectedService

The XC 9.3 SDK relies on the OData Connected Service tool v0.4.0 for it and OData Client 6.19.

Solution is to downgrade the OData Connected Service tool to v0.4 (or lower).

You can request this version at Sitecore support using reference number 404070 or (once available) download it here: https://github.com/OData/ODataConnectedService/releases (see also https://github.com/OData/ODataConnectedService/issues/85).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Joost mentioned:

Even if you are successful in generating the proxy and your site comes up, there is another issue when you try to invoke your custom action.

Here are the full steps:

1. Generate proxy using 6.19 version of odata, using odata connected
   services v4
2. Add reference to the new proxy in Sitecore project
3. Downgrade the odata nuget packages to v 6.19 in Sitecore project
   (ignore dependencies) Mark these odata dlls in the project to not
   deploy
4. Compile your project and deploy.

check out [Engine ProxyService shopcontainer threw an exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException'](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24385/engine-proxyservice-shopcontainer-threw-an-exception-of-type-system-missingmeth)

IDEALLY - your service proxy project that comes ootb should be added to the Sitecore project and odata version should be changed to 6.19 and then proxy should be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog to know where we can find right version of [Odata Service](https://sitecore-commerce.blogspot.com/2020/11/sitecore-commerce-service-proxy-error.html) vsix to setup in Visual Studio.
https://sitecore-commerce.blogspot.com/2020/11/sitecore-commerce-service-proxy-error.html